# Treehouse jQuery Challenge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

How can one use jQuery to select list items from an unordered list that has a specific class? The exact question reads "On the next line, use jQuery to select all list items (li) in an unordered list (ul) with the class of 'nav'?"

I have tried several times on treehouse but it won't let me pass!

```
$(".nav ul li");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your selector `$(".nav ul li")` means some `element with class nav has ul`, `if ul has class nav then try this`.

```
$("ul.nav li");
```

Comment: Just tried it again, it worked after i removed the space! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.nav').children('li')
```

would be a faster way to do this.